# RLS implementation in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have tried creating a relationship between two tables having many to many relations since it cant be done in Power BI, I have introduced an intermediate table and have created two relationships.After implementing RLS, the resulting rows are not according to a selected user [ please find image 5 for reference]. I don't know what I am missing out. Please find below the steps I have followed.

Creating 1st relationship
[image: Creating 1st relationship]

Creating 2nd relationship
[image: Creating 2nd relationship]

After creating two relationships
[image: After creating two relationships]

Implementing RLS
[image: Implementing RLS]

The final result
[image: The final result]

PFB the links,

Comment: It would help if you include some details about your tables and how they relate to each other, and also which version of Power BI you're using. You may need to use a bidirectional filter.

Comment: RLS = row-level security?

Comment: What are you expecting to see that you are not seeing?

Comment: This is a sample table which i have created to replicate the same problem i am facing real time. Yes i am using bidirectional filter for both relationship.Now the thing is when i select a particular user role to view data , it is showing all the data and not the user based one.

Comment: I am using the latest version of power bi desktop.

Comment: What is the warning message that you have on Vehicle_Entry table and have you tried to check what is USERNAME() returning and have you tried to use USERPRINCIPALNAME() instead?